# How do I specify a description for an \xrefitem in Doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

I am using the [`\xrefitem` command](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdxrefitem) to create a bunch of user-defined sections that are all automatically cross-referenced. For example, one of the aliases I use looks like this:

```
hack=\xrefitem hack \"Hack\" \"Wall of Shame\""
```

This all works well. The documentation is generated exactly as I want, and a link to the "Wall of Shame" appears on the "Related Pages" page:

[image: "Related Pages" page, with "Wall of Shame" link. Note the empty description field.]

But **I can't figure out how to add a description to the right of this link.** That empty description cell there is just begging to be filled. How can I make it happy?

Although the documentation doesn't indicate that this is valid syntax, I tried appending a description to the end of the alias, like this:

```
hack=\xrefitem hack \"Hack\" \"Wall of Shame\" \"Some sample descriptive text\""
```

but it didn't work; it just broke everything else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do

```
/*! @page hack 
 *  @brief Some sample descriptive text.
 *  @par
 */
```

Note that the dummy `@par` shouldn't have been needed, but it is currently needed due to a logic bug in doxygen, which I'll fix in the next release.

Comment: Thanks! I see that with this form, I can also add a detailed description; that is *excellent*. (Also, it appears to work fine on 1.8.4 without the `@par`, but I'll include it anyway just in case.)

Comment: The `@par` is only needed as a placeholder for a detailed description. If you are add a detailed description it can be omitted.